# Get all 52 weeks of the year and work days given the first day of the January of current year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to have some kind of loop that stores all weeks and i need business days for each week `Mon-Fri`.

> $year = date('Y');
>
> $firstDayOfJan = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of January {$year}"));

how would i set up a loop that will start from the first day of january and give me all weeks.
The output im looking for is the following:

example: first day of january on 2013 is Tuesday. After running the loop it should get the first week like this:

> Week 1 --> FROM: 01-01-2013 (TUEADAY FIRST DAY)  TO: 01-04-2013 (FRIDAY)
>
> Week 2 --> FROM: 01-07-2013 (MONDAY) TO: 01-11-2013 (FRIDAY)
>
> ... so on all weeks from monday to friday

---

Or to word it in a different kind [Source/Delref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146880/get-past-weeks-from-the-current-week-and-all-business-days-in-between-php):

---

#### Get past weeks from the current week and all business days in between PHP

I want to retrieve all past weeks from current week.

> $currYear = date("Y");
>
> $currDate = date("m-d-Y", time()); //get curr date
>
> for($i = $currDate; $i > 01-01-$currYear; $i--) (first of january of current year)) print all weeks

starting from current week i want to backtrack and get all the past weeks. So if im in the middle of July i want to be able to display all weeks before july till january 1st.

the week format has to be this:

> Week # 1 (January): FROM: from date TO: to date

any help appreciated thanks alot

Comment: Are you taking holidays off? What about mondays if the holiday is on a sunday and fridays if the holiday is on a saturday?

Comment: why a loop? you just need to know what day-of-week Jan 1st is and if the year's a leapyear. After that, it's just some simple mod 7 math.

Comment: i only need business days of all weeks in the year. it starts from Tuesday because January 1st was Tuesday in 2013 and not Monday. Marc B can you help me out with mod 7 math ?

Comment: Use the datetime class for that. And use the search on this website, we have all imaginary PHP date and time questions already answered. Really. The only thing you need to do is to search. - http://php.net/datetime

Comment: Just seeing you duplicated your question. I put the text from there to here in case it gets delete. I suggest you write that up a little so it is not that rough. Never-ever duplicate your own questions btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I count right, there are 53 weeks you need to take into account for 2013:

1. Week 01 --> FROM: 2013-01-01 (Tuesday) TO: 2013-01-04 (Friday)
2. Week 02 --> FROM: 2013-01-07 (Monday) TO: 2013-01-11 (Friday)
3. Week 03 --> FROM: 2013-01-14 (Monday) TO: 2013-01-18 (Friday)
4. Week 04 --> FROM: 2013-01-21 (Monday) TO: 2013-01-25 (Friday)
5. Week 05 --> FROM: 2013-01-28 (Monday) TO: 2013-02-01 (Friday)
6. Week 06 --> FROM: 2013-02-04 (Monday) TO: 2013-02-08 (Friday)
7. Week 07 --> FROM: 2013-02-11 (Monday) TO: 2013-02-15 (Friday)
8. Week 08 --> FROM: 2013-02-18 (Monday) TO: 2013-02-22 (Friday)
9. Week 09 --> FROM: 2013-02-25 (Monday) TO: 2013-03-01 (Friday)
10. Week 10 --> FROM: 2013-03-04 (Monday) TO: 2013-03-08 (Friday)
11. Week 11 --> FROM: 2013-03-11 (Monday) TO: 2013-03-15 (Friday)
12. Week 12 --> FROM: 2013-03-18 (Monday) TO: 2013-03-22 (Friday)
13. Week 13 --> FROM: 2013-03-25 (Monday) TO: 2013-03-29 (Friday)
14. Week 14 --> FROM: 2013-04-01 (Monday) TO: 2013-04-05 (Friday)
15. Week 15 --> FROM: 2013-04-08 (Monday) TO: 2013-04-12 (Friday)
16. Week 16 --> FROM: 2013-04-15 (Monday) TO: 2013-04-19 (Friday)
17. Week 17 --> FROM: 2013-04-22 (Monday) TO: 2013-04-26 (Friday)
18. Week 18 --> FROM: 2013-04-29 (Monday) TO: 2013-05-03 (Friday)
19. Week 19 --> FROM: 2013-05-06 (Monday) TO: 2013-05-10 (Friday)
20. Week 20 --> FROM: 2013-05-13 (Monday) TO: 2013-05-17 (Friday)
21. Week 21 --> FROM: 2013-05-20 (Monday) TO: 2013-05-24 (Friday)
22. Week 22 --> FROM: 2013-05-27 (Monday) TO: 2013-05-31 (Friday)
23. Week 23 --> FROM: 2013-06-03 (Monday) TO: 2013-06-07 (Friday)
24. Week 24 --> FROM: 2013-06-10 (Monday) TO: 2013-06-14 (Friday)
25. Week 25 --> FROM: 2013-06-17 (Monday) TO: 2013-06-21 (Friday)
26. Week 26 --> FROM: 2013-06-24 (Monday) TO: 2013-06-28 (Friday)
27. Week 27 --> FROM: 2013-07-01 (Monday) TO: 2013-07-05 (Friday)
28. Week 28 --> FROM: 2013-07-08 (Monday) TO: 2013-07-12 (Friday)
29. Week 29 --> FROM: 2013-07-15 (Monday) TO: 2013-07-19 (Friday)
30. Week 30 --> FROM: 2013-07-22 (Monday) TO: 2013-07-26 (Friday)
31. Week 31 --> FROM: 2013-07-29 (Monday) TO: 2013-08-02 (Friday)
32. Week 32 --> FROM: 2013-08-05 (Monday) TO: 2013-08-09 (Friday)
33. Week 33 --> FROM: 2013-08-12 (Monday) TO: 2013-08-16 (Friday)
34. Week 34 --> FROM: 2013-08-19 (Monday) TO: 2013-08-23 (Friday)
35. Week 35 --> FROM: 2013-08-26 (Monday) TO: 2013-08-30 (Friday)
36. Week 36 --> FROM: 2013-09-02 (Monday) TO: 2013-09-06 (Friday)
37. Week 37 --> FROM: 2013-09-09 (Monday) TO: 2013-09-13 (Friday)
38. Week 38 --> FROM: 2013-09-16 (Monday) TO: 2013-09-20 (Friday)
39. Week 39 --> FROM: 2013-09-23 (Monday) TO: 2013-09-27 (Friday)
40. Week 40 --> FROM: 2013-09-30 (Monday) TO: 2013-10-04 (Friday)
41. Week 41 --> FROM: 2013-10-07 (Monday) TO: 2013-10-11 (Friday)
42. Week 42 --> FROM: 2013-10-14 (Monday) TO: 2013-10-18 (Friday)
43. Week 43 --> FROM: 2013-10-21 (Monday) TO: 2013-10-25 (Friday)
44. Week 44 --> FROM: 2013-10-28 (Monday) TO: 2013-11-01 (Friday)
45. Week 45 --> FROM: 2013-11-04 (Monday) TO: 2013-11-08 (Friday)
46. Week 46 --> FROM: 2013-11-11 (Monday) TO: 2013-11-15 (Friday)
47. Week 47 --> FROM: 2013-11-18 (Monday) TO: 2013-11-22 (Friday)
48. Week 48 --> FROM: 2013-11-25 (Monday) TO: 2013-11-29 (Friday)
49. Week 49 --> FROM: 2013-12-02 (Monday) TO: 2013-12-06 (Friday)
50. Week 50 --> FROM: 2013-12-09 (Monday) TO: 2013-12-13 (Friday)
51. Week 51 --> FROM: 2013-12-16 (Monday) TO: 2013-12-20 (Friday)
52. Week 52 --> FROM: 2013-12-23 (Monday) TO: 2013-12-27 (Friday)
53. Week 01 --> FROM: 2013-12-30 (Monday) TO: 2013-12-31 (Tuesday)

You can get such a listing by making use of the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/DatePeriod) class, it is pretty flexible.

I did it the following (pseudo-code):

```
for each $monday [
    in the period starting from the first day of the first week of 2013 
    with an interval of one week
    until 2013-12-31 23:59:59
] do: {
    output "X. Week XX --> "
    for each $day [
        in the period starting from $monday
        with an interval of one day
        repeated four times
    ] | [
        filter all days not having the year 
    ] | [
        filter out the first and last
    ] {
        output 
            "FROM" if has next "TO" otherwise
            ": " format($date, "Y-m-d (l)")
    }
}
```

As this code shows, I've solved this using iterators. `DatePeriod` is already traversable, but I also needed a `DatePeriodYearFilter` to filter the dates in a specific year (see [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/FilterIterator) and the `FirstAndLastIterator` was needed, which is basically an extension to [`CachingIterator`](http://php.net/CachingIterator).

The example code:

```
$year = 2013;

$weeksPeriod = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime("$year-W01-1"),
    new DateInterval('P1W'),
    new DateTime("$year-12-31T23:59:59Z")
);

foreach ($weeksPeriod as $week => $monday) {

    $daysPeriod   = new DatePeriod($monday, new DateInterval('P1D'), 4);
    $daysFiltered = new DatePeriodYearFilter($daysPeriod, $year);
    $days         = new FirstAndLastIterator($daysFiltered);

    printf(" 1. Week %s --> ", $monday->format('W'));

    foreach ($days as $day => $date) {
        $label = $days->hasNext() ? 'FROM' : 'TO';
        printf("%s: %s ", $label, $date->format('Y-m-d (l)'));
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

Making use of PHP 5.5's upcomming generator feature then would even allow to filter out weeks that don't have and start and end date in a iterative fashion quite easily so wrapping all this into an iterator that only returns each week  with FROM (if available) and TO dates.

In PHP 5.4 this could be simulated having some array conversion, which also seems okay as this is about not that many entries. Here the example code:

```
$workdaysOfWeekForMonday = function(DateTime $monday) use ($year) {

    $daysPeriod   = new DatePeriod($monday, new DateInterval('P1D'), 4);
    $daysFiltered = new DatePeriodYearFilter($daysPeriod, $year);
    $days         = new FirstAndLastIterator($daysFiltered);

    return array_map(function(DateTime $date) {return $date->format('Y-m-d (l)');}, iterator_to_array($days, false));
};

$result = array_filter(array_map($workdaysOfWeekForMonday, iterator_to_array($weeksPeriod)));

print_r($result);
```

The result (shortened, exemplary for the year 2017 here which in it's real last week would have had no working weekdays, now properly filtered):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-01-02 (Monday)
            [1] => 2017-01-06 (Friday)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-01-09 (Monday)
            [1] => 2017-01-13 (Friday)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-01-16 (Monday)
            [1] => 2017-01-20 (Friday)
        )

    ...

    [49] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-12-11 (Monday)
            [1] => 2017-12-15 (Friday)
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-12-18 (Monday)
            [1] => 2017-12-22 (Friday)
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-12-25 (Monday)
            [1] => 2017-12-29 (Friday)
        )

)
```

And here the code for the iterators I have added for these examples: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/4447499).